# (CLOSED) AWS CloudTrail does not log all user activities?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudtrail

I am currently building a simple application in my org's AWS to track SNS un-subscriptions activities. So far, I have not found any way to get SNS to trigger/create event based on unsubscription activities. The only way I thought would be possible was to track it from CloudTrail, and from there trigger a Lambda script to trigger another SNS for notification purpose. Here's the interesting part. After multiple attempts to subscribe and unsubscribe myself over the past few days, I realised that not all unsubscriptions were recorded (I would say maybe only 10-20% were recorded). The very last record was dated 5 days ago.

Maybe I am missing out something here. Any experts could point out/recommend other more reliable methods to track SNS unsubscriptions? Thanks and have a great day ahead!

[Update] Turns out that CloudTrail can only record unsubscriptions initiated by ADMIN (through the management console), NOT those initiated by subscribers themselves (through their email). Are there any ways to track subscriber-initiated unsubs?

Comment: Are you saying that _some_ of the unsubscriptions were in the CloudTrail logs, but not _all_ of them?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeap that’s right.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that SNS won't log unauthenticated subscription confirmations or unsubscribes. According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-logging-using-cloudtrail.html):

"When you are not logged in to Amazon Web Services (unauthenticated mode) and either the ConfirmSubscription or Unsubscribe actions are invoked, then they will not be logged to CloudTrail. Such as, when you choose the provided link in an email notification to confirm a pending subscription to a topic, the ConfirmSubscription action is invoked in unauthenticated mode. In this example, the ConfirmSubscription action would not be logged to CloudTrail."